# "Undefined control sequence" problem in memoir class?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, chapters

I use `memoir` class and want to customize the table-of-contents and chapters style. When I use `\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]` I get this error after the *second compilation*:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\chapternumberline ... \@tempdima {\@chapapp@head
\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum \h...
l.2 ...pter}{\chapternumberline {1}Chapter One}{3}
```

My code:

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} 
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\definecolor{secnum}{RGB}{13,151,225}
\definecolor{ptcbackground}{RGB}{212,237,252}
\definecolor{ptctitle}{RGB}{0,177,235}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 2.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      \colorbox{ptctitle}{\strut%
        \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-7pt\relax][l]{%
          \color{white}\bfseries\sffamily#1%
          \nobreak\hfill\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}}\par\smallskip
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\subsection{Section One Two}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}

\end{document}
```

In `book` class, however, it works with no error!

Comment: You have invisible characters U+200E "left to right mark" in your lines 13, 32, 33. If you remove these, your MWE compiles just fine with either `book` or `memoir`. (I found these characters by copying the _entire_ line for which I was given an error and pasting it into the "UTF8 String" field on www.isthisthingon.org/unicode, which gave me a list of all characters used.) Which editor are you using? These invisible character questions have been popping up fairly frequently recently, perhaps there's a bug in the editor. (Also, voting to close as _too localized_, let us know if it's not working)

Comment: The definition you have been modifying stems from `book.cls`, so it is clear it works there. `memoir.cls` has a completely different way of defining chapters, so you can easily produce a conflict by "injecting" code from `book.cls` there. Document structure etc. are completely in the resposibility of document classes, so you need to consider which class you are using. Please modify the code from `memoir.cls` instead.

Comment: Because my language is `persian`, that "left to right mark" characters is there. How should i do for modifying this definition of chapter?

Comment: @doncherry The right-to-left marks are giving errors when processing the MWE with `pdflatex` (I wonder whether it works with XeTeX???), but that's not the error message reported by the OP. That one really stems from transplanting `book.cls` code to memoir.

Comment: @mohammadazadi I suggest you reformulate the title of your question and also explain a little more what you tried to do, to keep your question from getting closed.

Comment: @StephanLehmke I failed to see that the error messages only pop up when you compile for the second time, i.e. when the ToC is actually set. I'll edit the question post to remove the U+200E's and vote to reopen. Sorry about the closing, Mohammad!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition you have been modifying stems from `book.cls`, so it is clear it works there. `memoir.cls` has a completely different way of defining chapters, so you can easily produce a conflict by "injecting" code from `book.cls` there. Document structure etc. are completely in the resposibility of document classes, so you need to consider which class you are using. Please modify the code from memoir.cls instead.

Here is a starting point. I tried to be as "minimally invasive" as possible, but I'm really no Memoir expert. From the look of it, it'll need some more fiddling, but the definitions are really quite different:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{2.0em \@plus\p@}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\l@chapapp}[3]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \cftchapterbreak
    \vskip \cftbeforechapterskip
    {%\leftskip \cftchapterindent\relax
     \memRTLleftskip \cftchapterindent\relax
%%%     \rightskip \@tocrmarg
     \memRTLrightskip \@tocrmarg
%%%     \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parfillskip -\memRTLrightskip
     \parindent \cftchapterindent\relax
     \@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \let\@cftbsnum \cftchapterpresnum
     \let\@cftasnum \cftchapteraftersnum
     \let\@cftasnumb \cftchapteraftersnumb
     \def\@chapapp@head{#3}%
     \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\cftchapterfont\@chapapp@head}%
     \addtolength{\@tempdima}{\cftchapternumwidth}%
%%%     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     \advance\memRTLleftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\memRTLleftskip
      \colorbox{ptctitle}{\strut%
        \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-7pt\relax][l]{%
          \color{white}\cftchapterfont#1%
          \nobreak{\cftchapterleader}\nobreak
    \cftchapterformatpnum{#2}%
    \cftchapterafterpnum}}\par\smallskip}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Thank you. I place `\def\@chapapp@head{}` befor `\setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}‎` in my code and it works fine.